# i am working on media player i want to chnage the brightness of the screen when user slide on the left sideof the screen

Tags: android, gesture

i use the following code to detect which side the user slide the user but it is not working at all as it suppose to be work

```
    relay.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchevent) {
            switch (touchevent.getAction())
            {
                // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    x1 = touchevent.getX();
                    y1 = touchevent.getY();
                    Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, x1+""+x2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    x2 = touchevent.getX();
                    y2 = touchevent.getY();

                                             //if left to right sweep event on screen
                    if (x1 < x2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // if right to left sweep event on screen
                    if (x1 > x2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                    if (y1 < y2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                                             //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                    if (y1 > y2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

           // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    });
```

can anyone help me that how i can detect the user has slide on the right side of the activity in upward or downward direction

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your activity

```
private float startPoint,endPoint;
static final int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 150;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          startPoint = event.getX();                          
      break;          
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          endPoint = event.getX();
          float dX = endPoint- startPoint;
          if (Math.abs(dX) > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE)
          {
              //left to right swipe
          }                         
      break;    
    }            
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);        
}
```

Comment: return super.onTouchEvent(event);

Comment: can you post other conditions also

Comment: totaly different condition from my case